# What src attribute will do in amp-ad component?

Tags: amp-html, amp-ad

If i add the src attribute, which is available for `amp-ad` component as specified [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad), what will it do? Will it load the specified script before the amp-ad component comes into the visible area?

Code Sample:

```html
<amp-ad type="taboola"
    src="https://cdn.taboola.com/libtrc/amp-demo/loader.js"
    width="400"
    height="300"
    layout="responsive"
    data-publisher="amp-demo"
    data-mode="thumbnails-a"
    data-placement="Ads Example"
    data-article="auto">
  </amp-ad>
```

Comment: Yes. As per google amp documentation 

Use this attribute to load a script tag for the specified ad network. This can be used for ad networks that require exactly a single script tag to be inserted in the page.

Comment: yes, do I have to specify the url of js script? will it be called before ad widget comes into the view area of page?

Comment: Normally the amp-ads loads asynchronously. You can specify the url of the JS Script